# Where can i find all the elements that are currently available to be used in the .world file?

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey, I want to create a sand surface in gazebo,  then design a wheel on solidworks and import it on gazebo so to be able to test the interactions of the two. My first task is to create the sand surface, to do that i thought to create a box and transform it to sand(testbed) by setting the physical properties for it.

Where can i find all the elements that are available to be used in the .world file?

If not all the elements that i want to use are available, can i set my own ones by any way?

Also any general suggestions/ideas regarding the whole project will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24165/where-can-i-find-all-the-elements-that-are-currently-available-to-be-used-in-the-.world-file?/) by [Kyriakos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/20484/kyriakos/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> Where can i find all the elements that are available to be used in the .world file?

Here: http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=world

> If not all the elements that i want to use are available, can i set my own ones by any way?

You currently can't do that directly into `<world>`, but you could add them inside a `<plugin>` tag that loads your custom plugin and parses them.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0